# How to upload csv file to API using python

Tags: python, api, csv, python-requests

Tried this

```
response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, files = files)
```

where file is

```
files = [
  ('file', open('D:/cf_upload-sheet/new_data.csv','rb'))
]
```

Getting this error on server end: ,"method":"PUT","exception":"RuntimeError - Only .csv, .xls and .xlsx files are allowed."

Did anyone face the same issue? and how to resolve it?

Comment: Could it have something to do with you opening the file as `'rb'` (read binary)?

Comment: I have tried it with just 'r' but the method that I want to find is how do I pass CSV file(.csv) to the API

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to make it a dictionary instead?

```
files = {'file': open('D:/cf_upload-sheet/new_data.csv','rb')}
```

EDIT: I think it is possible to send other details about the file based on this: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

```
files = {
    "file": (
        "new_data.csv",
        open("D:/cf_upload-sheet/new_data.csv", "rb"),
        "text/csv",
        {"Expires": "0"},
    )
}
```

Comment: b'{"success":false,"error":{"code":215,"type":"error","message":"Missing Required Param"}}'
This is the error I get as it is not identifying the file that is passed

Comment: Any documentation on the API?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not available but what I know is it expects a CSV file input to work. The question is how do I pass CSV file from python to this API

Comment: The error message tells me that it is received at server end but the file format is a mismatch

Comment: Could it be that you are reading it in binary mode? Try: `files = {'file': open('D:/cf_upload-sheet/new_data.csv','r')}`